# why comma,address-of, logical AND and logical OR operators should not be overloaded in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, operator-overloading, logical-operators

Can someone please explain with examples why it is not a good practice to overload comma, address-of, logical AND, and logical OR operators in c++?

Comment: If you overload the comma operator, you're the reason STL changed his C++ STL implementation to do `a, void(), b` where appropriate.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as 'primarily opinion based'

Comment: Who said that and when?

Answer (score 6):

The underlying reason is that overloaded versions of these operators behave differently than the builtin versions. This can lead to substantial confusion (of humans) reading/writing code.

1. **logical operators `&&` and `||`** The builtin versions exhibit *short circuit* optimisation: in an expression like `a && b`, `a` is evaluated first and only if `true`, `b` is also evaluated; similarly, in `a || b`, `a` is evaluated first and only if `false`, `b` is also evaluated. Overloaded operators `&&` and `||` don't have short-circuit optimisation (both `a` and `b` are always evaluated) and also the order of evaluation of the arguments is not specified.
2. **Comma operator** The builtin version guarantees that the arguments are evaluated in the order they occur, i.e. in `a,b` `a` is evaluated first then `b`. With an overloaded comma operator, this guarantee is lost (and instead the function parameter mechanism comes into play).
3. **address-of operator** There is a potential confusion between the builtin address-of operator `&` and the overloaded one when applied to objects of incomplete type. Consider this code

   ```
   struct type;            // forward declaration: type is (as of yet) incomplete

   #include <memory>
   void foo(type &obj)     // allowed: take object of incomplete type by reference
   {
     auto ptr1 = &obj;                  // address of obj -- or not?
     auto ptr2 = std::addressof(obj);   // always address of obj    
   }

   // possibly in a different translation unit:
   struct type
   {
     type* operator&() { return nullptr; }
   };
   ```

   This code exhibits [**unspecified behaviour**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1458): the compiler can implement either version of the `&` operator in `foo()`, but the human writing the code of `foo()` cannot know this or which operator will be used.
   This problem is avoided when using [`std::addressof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof) as for `ptr2`, which obtains the equivalent of the builtin address-of operator, even if `type` has an overloaded `&` operator.

Comment: The `operator&` case is now unspecified, per [CWG1458](http://wg21.link/CWG1458).

Answer (score 4):

If someone reads code and is seeing a `if(a && b)`, what will he/she think?
If a and b are native types like `bool` or `int`, everybody knows how it works.

If they are class objects, most people would expect that the class provides an `operator bool()` or similar to query what bool it should be, before applying `&&`. Nobody will expect that it is a "fancy" way to write `if(a.myMethod(b))`, and nobodywill check in the class definition => Everyone will misunderstand and/or be confused what purpose of the condition is.
tldr, don't use the builtin `&&` as abbreviation for unrelated method calls.

The same is valid for `||` and `,`.

As for the address operator, in addition to the reading confusion issue, it's very present when writing code too: Pointer addresses normally can be acquired for any variable of any type, and no one will check your class definition before doing that.

Besides readability etc., if and in what order the arguments are evaluated differs:

For `if(a&&b)` normally, if a is *`false`*, `b` isn't even checked anymore, because the whole condition can only be false. If you have something like eg. `if(a && func1()) func2();` where the return value of `func2()` matters, `func1()` is executed *only* if `a` is `true`, and only if both are true `func2()` is executed. With an overloaded `&&`, `func1()` is *always* executed. Depending what it does, this may not be what you want.

With `||`, it's similar: If the first parameter is *`true`*, the second parameter normally isn't looked at anymore, because the whole condition is true anyways. With an overload, the parameter is always evaluated.

A normal comma operator `a,b` has the guarentee that `a` is evaluated/executed before `b`; with an overload it can be in any order.

Comment: Code readability is an issue. But if you check this link https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL10-CPP.+Do+not+overload+the+ampersand,+comma,+logical+AND+or+logical+OR+operators, the reason explained here is difficult for me to understand. So, I asked the question which is now downvoted.

Comment: @bornfree I'm not talking about readability only. ... About your link, I'll add that...